# Spring - Mongo configuration class path

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I have the following simple project structure:

[image]

Here are the implementation of these files:

Tryton - boot class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Tryton {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Tryton.class, args);
    }
}
```

UserRepository - Mongo Repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
}
```

UserController - REST controller

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }
}
```

MongoConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
@ConfigurationProperties("foo")
class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Value("${mongodb.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${mongodb.port}")
    private int port;
    @Value("${mongodb.databaseName}")
    private String databaseName;

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return databaseName;
    }

    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return new Mongo(host, port);
    }

}
```

It is very simple app: I inject `UserRepository` into `UserController`. Then I config MongoDB connection details in `MongoConfig`. Now everything works fine. But when I move `MongoConfig` into */configs* package then the problem occurs:

[image]

And now the app **can't start**.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.tryton.controllers.UserController required a bean of type 'com.tryton.repositories.UserRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.tryton.repositories.UserRepository' in your configuration.
```

Why does `MongoConfig` location change makes spring not able to recognise `UserRepository` as a `MongoRepository`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after moving to config package the default `@EnableMongoRepositories` target has been changed. Or more precisely, the *base package* has been changed to `com.tryton.configs.*`. Spring searching now for mongo repositories in this package.

you have now to add *basePackages* in `@EnableMongoRepositories` - annotation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.tryton.repositories"})
@ConfigurationProperties("foo")
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
      [...]
}
```

Make sure your `MongoConfig` is public.

Comment: make sure MongoConfig is public.

Comment: how do you annotated `UserRepository` ?

Comment: I didn't annotate it. Do I need to?

Comment: Yes, `@Repository`. You need implementation for your Interface.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125630/discussion-between-humberd-and-dit).